# Vue js use select in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to learn vue . I grabbed a demo project and have much of it working but I am not sure I under stand what this does.

```
 const search = ref("");
 const movies= ref([]);
```

in the template and other places it then accesses the value using search.value. Why use Ref("") ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ref()` allows us to create a "reference" to any value and pass it around without losing reactivity.

The beauty behind that is the fact that you can create reactive properties outside your Vue component. Inside a plain js (or ts) file, just import `"ref"` from the `"vue"` package, and then create a reactive property, e.g.

```js
const msg = ref("hello")
```

For the examples you provided, you're simply initializing the variables with an empty string for `search` and empty array for `movies`.

Answer (score 1):

In Vue 3, ref() makes a variable reactive.

https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-core.html#ref